# Should search be case sensitive for tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

Searching for [C#] will automatically convert the search to [c#] and return results.

Searching for [C#] and anything else returns 0 results. The search is already capable of parsing out tags, so how come it doesn't convert the tag to lowercase if I were to search for something like "[C#] body:repository"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually in the process of re-writing the search parser completely, already part of this is lower-casing anything inside a tag...so you'll see this rolled out early next week.

*Update:* Sorry! I forgot to update this question, this is now live across the network.